# Javascript oop undefined value: Method to add a scope?

Tags: javascript, oop, scope, prototype, apply

**Code:**

```js
var test = {
    con: true
};

var conrun= function(){
    return this.con;
};

Function.prototype.curry = function(scope){
    var fn = this;
    var scope = scope||window;
    return function(){
        fn.apply(scope,arguments);
    }
}

conrun = conrun.curry(test);
alert(conrun());
//result:undefined
```

"curry" method, the function will return, "conrun" fonkiyonuna "test" add to the scope of...

What should I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `curry` loses the return value. Change that line to:

```
return fn.apply(scope, arguments);
```

Comment: `return function(){return fn.apply(scope,arguments);};
//result:true
`